# How to efficiently store an int into bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am developing a program that uses the python 3.7 socket library to send and receive information, and I want it to be efficient network wise (doesn't need to be all that fast, I don't have enough time to build it in C) meaning if I want to send the number 1024, I should only need 2 bytes.

In C, all that needs to be done is cast the int as a string, access the first 2 bytes and that is that (2 byte number to a 2 byte array/"string").

In Python, even when using the bytes structures, I always end up with something of the sort b'(\x8a', which is significantly larger than the needed byte amount.

The socket.send function only accepts byte objects, so I tried parsing the int as so (to_bytes and from_bytes), but ended up with an even bigger amount of bytes (b'(\x8a') than if I had used str()

When I set the receive buffer to 2 bytes for a number like 1024, I want to receive 1024 and not 10.

Comment: *How* are you converting the `int` to a byte string? `struct.pack("!H", 10378)` will return `b'(\x8a'`, not `b'\x00\x00(\x8a'`.

Comment: I tried doing IntVar.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big')

Comment: `(10378).to_bytes(2, 'big')` also returns `b'(\x8a'`, not `b'\x00\x00(\x8a'`.

Comment: I used b'\x00\x00(\x8a' and 1024 as an example but they aren't related. My bad. I will clear it up

Comment: My point is, the example call to `to_bytes` you showed *does* produce a 2-byte string, so I'm not really sure what the problem is. It's not useful to expect smaller numbers to produce smaller byte strings, though, because the receiving end has to know how many bytes to *use* before it can decode your value.

Comment: If **EDIT 1 I was using b'\x00\x00(\x8a' instead of b'(\x8a' because it came directly from the actual output, instead of the 1024 example, my bad.** is your solution post it as own answer and not as edit in question.

Comment: You are right. My call to send was not direct and was parsed (with str), thus the results that I was seing. Sorry for all the confusion, and thanks for the help.

Comment: ZF007 it wasn't, I messed up the example. God I made this question is a mess. Should I just delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pack numbers into bytes, you'll want the `struct` module.

```
>>> struct.pack('>H', 1024)
b'\x04\x00'
```

This packs the data `1024` into a single `unsigned short` aka `uint16_t` (`H`), in big-endian format (`>`). This gives the two bytes `04 00`.

In practice, `struct` is usually used to pack a lot of data together, using longer format strings:

```
data = struct.pack('>bbbbHHiid', dat1, dat2, dat3...)
```

You probably see now why that module gets its name!

If you really only need to send a single number, you can use the built-in `int.to_bytes` method:

```
>>> (1024).to_bytes(2, 'big')
b'\x04\x00'
```

The first argument is the number of bytes to use, the second is the endianness.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. My problem is that when I send that result through the socket, it sends b'\x04\x00' as characters and therefore \ and x are 2 bytes. I will try to provide example code.

Comment: @Sphen It sounds like your problem isn't with packing the int into bytes, then, but in your socket handling.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. The problem was not directly here, further in the code I was doing an str call.