# How do I hash integers and strings inputs using murmurhash3

Tags: python, hash, typeerror, murmurhash

I'm looking to get a hash value for string and integer inputs.
Using murmurhash3, I'm able to do it for strings but not integers:

```
pip install murmurhash3
import mmh3
mmh3.hash(34)
```

Returns the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
```

I could convert it to bytes like this:

```
mmh3.hash(bytes(34))
```

But then I'll get an error message if the input is string

How do I overcome this **without** converting the integer to string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to efficiently store an int into bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799021/how-to-efficiently-store-an-int-into-bytes)

Comment: Thanks @Sneftel but this only solves the issue of converting integers. As mentioned in my question I know how to do that.
 I need a way to convert both strings and integers.

Comment: I edited the title to ensure this point is clear

Answer (score 2):

> How do I overcome this **without** converting the integer to string?

You can't. Or more precisely, you need to convert it to `bytes` or `str` in *some* way, but it needn't be a human-readable text form like `b'34'`/`'34'`. A common approach on Python 3 would be:

```
my_int = 34  # Or some other value
my_int_as_bytes = my_int.to_bytes((my_int.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'little')
```

which makes a minimalist raw bytes representation of the original `int` (regardless of length); for `34`, you'd get `b'"'` (because it only takes one byte to store it, so you're basically getting a `bytes` object with its ordinal value), but for larger `int`s it still works (unlike mucking about with `chr`), and it's always as small as possible (getting 8 bits of data per byte, rather than a titch over 3 bits per byte as you'd get converting to a text string).

If you're on Python 2 (WHY?!? It's been end-of-life for nearly a year), `int.to_bytes` doesn't exist, but you can fake it with moderate efficiency in various ways, e.g. (only handling non-negative values, unlike `to_bytes` which handles signed values with a simple flag):

```
 from binascii import unhexlify

 my_int_as_bytes = unhexlify('%x' % (my_int,))
```

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger.
As mentioned in my question I thought about converting the integer to bytes but then strings won't be accepted.

Should I use an if statement that will convert bytes but not strings? I hope there's a better way.

Comment: @Niv: Yeah, `if isinstance(x, int):` test to control conversion seems the reasonable approach. You have two unrelated data types, you have to handle them differently. An unconditional `str(x)` might work on Python 2 (at the expense of longer strings from `int`), but on Python 3 it'll make `bytes` not work properly. Best to handle different types differently.